# if div has content show div

Tags: jquery, animation, html

ok heres what i have... it works fine but it looks for a word rather than content. i just want it to show when there is any content..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       if ($("#box3:contains('Product')").length) {
          $('#third').show();
       }                                           
    });
```

i dont think you need the html for this

it looks for 'Product' how do i make it just look for content >0

```
<div id="first" class="tab" >
    <div class="tabtxt">
        <a>DETAILS</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="second">
    <div class="tabtxt">
        <a>INSPIRATION</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="third" style="display:none">
    <div class="tabtxt">
        <a>NOTES</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="boxholder">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; display:block" class="box" id="box1">
        <div style="padding: 10px; line-height:16px">
            %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; display:none" class="box" id="box2">
        <div style="padding: 10px; line-height:16px">
            %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; display:none" class="box" id="box3">
        <div style="padding: 10px; line-height:16px">
            %%Panel.UPC%%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

its an interspire shopping cart so the %%panel.upc%% calls in something inserted through the admin panel. in this case if there is nothing.. it shows as blank space in the code (viewing source in browser).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to check for **text**, you can use the `text()` method:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("#box3").text().length > 0) {
     $('#third').show();
   }                                           
 });
```

Or for html:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("#box3").html().length > 0) {
     $('#third').show();
   }                                           
 });
```

Comment: Checking for `.text()` isn't a good idea here, for example: `<img src="something.jpg" />`

Comment: @Nick Craver: I have also posted the `html()` method, just thought he may only want to check for text not other elements :)

Comment: hmm this is working for me i added a bs id to #box3 div so its looking for the inner box. it still recognized the whitespace so it was showing #third... i just made it "> 5" rather than 0 and it works .... thankyou ! =D

Answer (score 18):

*For the updated question:* Check the trimmed text of the inner `<div>`, like this:

```
 if ($.trim($("#box3 div").html())) {
   $('#third').show();
 }
```

*Previous answer:* If you want to show if it has *anything*, then checking [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) against [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) works:

```
 if ($("#box3:not(:empty)").length) {
   $('#third').show();
 }
```

If you want to check for any elements (not possibly whitespace only), then use [`:has(*)`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), like this:

```
 if ($("#box3:has(*)").length) {
   $('#third').show();
 }
```

Comment: no not working... there is another div inside so maybe it sees that as something? i'll post the html

Comment: @Alex - absolutely it'll see that, if you want to check if something *else* is empty we'll need the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the CSS3 selector `:empty`

```
div#empty-div:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

The `:empty` selector is only targeting just empty elements, without white space.

Answer (score 1):

Trim can be used to check the length

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("#box3").html().trim().length > 0) {
     $('#third').show();
   }                                           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for the HTML's length inside your selector:

```
if ($("#box3").html().length) {
    $('#third').show();
}
```