# display to loong text in a table and color a row of a table if something is true

Tags: php, html, css

guys I have a weird question maybe... I work on a home project using Mysql php and css to make a database program for myself. the idea is I have a Mysql database and using html/php i input the data in to the Mysql database. I get the results in a table... Know to the problem.. I display the whole table in the web page and some fields are to long and don't fit in the table.. i use

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
     border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and now the text fits in the table page BUT! know I can't read  the whole text... so I want it to make it like this: when I hover over the text witch doesn`t fit in the table to aper the whole text so I can read it? how do i do that?

and a quick second question... in the text I have a price filed and I would like to make it like this. when the price field is empty  hte whole row or the filed "price" would be colored red , and if the filed "price" has a value the field would be green? is there a way to do that using php and css?

Comment: You could try something first and if it doesn't work, come back here. But let me give you a hint: Make an extra `div` that gets filled up with data when the original table-cell-content is over x characters long. Put this div on a display:none (or visibility hidden) and make it appear on hover. Then you could use something like this to check if a div has content and has to be created in the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893440/if-div-has-content-show-div

Comment: For the second question, you could create two class, `.empty { background-color : red; }` and `.filled { background-color : green; }`, and apply at runtime when you get your database value back. Please provide a Php code for each question so we can precisely answer your matter.

Answer (score 0):

Store the text in the title attribute of the TD element of the table. Then when you hover the ellipsised text, a tip will show up with the whole text.

Comment: I cannot add a comment yet, not enough reputation, so I add it here. I meant something like this: echo "<td title='".$row['idforrepair']."'>" . $row['idforrepair'] . " </td>";

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what's going on as I can't see but I can guess what you want to do? I'm guessing you've used `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to create those dots when there's too much text within a `<td>`. The easiest method I can see without using javascript is to do the opposite when hovered over with the mouse. Although! The disadvantage of just using CSS is that there's no guarantee this method will show all the text. Here's my simple example:

```
td:hover{width:auto;height:auto;text-overflow:clip;}
```

But! Bare in mind that the `<td>` is restricted to it's parents width and height, so the `<td>` may still no show the whole text if the parent is too small for the child to be large enough to fit the text in.

Another method would be to use javascript to create an on click event which will display the text in a separate element which can be manipulated to show the entire string from your database.

Answer (score 0):

iv done this:

```css
td:hover{

  overflow:visible;
text-decoration: underline;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color:blue;
position: absolute;


background-color: #EEEEEE;
margin-top: 10px;

}
```

d if it
and its working relative fine now I want a filed to be color red if its empty and green if its with value. is there a way to do that? without java? i don`t have much clue of java script.

i want thsi 2 rows to becom red when there is no value inserted

echo "" . " ";
  echo "" . " ";

how can it be done?